# How to implement file operations with QT and SQLite

Tags: sql, sqlite, qt

Greetz,

I'm very curious on how to use basic file operations within QT and SQLite and wondering if there are current examples. My ideas are things like;

- OnAppOpen - create tables in an :memory: database (just call new file)
- OnFileSave - copy everything in :memory: into a file on disk
- OnFileOpen - copy everything from file on disk to :memory:
- OnFileNew - delete current :memory: database and Create a new one (OnAppOpen)

or something like

- AppOpen
- FileNew - disconnect from database and create new one with :memory: name
- FileSave - get current database name

Any help with this would be more than appreciated, thx.

Comment: I've read your question several times, and am struggling to understand what the problem is. It sounds like you have a good understanding of an approach to try - so can you explain what information you want?

Answer (score 1):

dbAdapter example if you want to save Logs per se.

```
public class DBAdapter {
    static final String ________________ (xtimes u need it)

    static final String DATABASE_CREATE = "CREATE TABLE ('_______');
    final Context context;
    DatabaseHelper DBHelper;
    SQLiteDatabase db;

    public DBAdapter(Context ctx)
    {
        this.context = ctx;
        DBHelper = new DatabaseHelper(context);
    }
    private static class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper
    {
        DatabaseHelper(Context context)
        {
            super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
        }
        @Override
        public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db)
        {
            try {
                db.execSQL(DATABASE_CREATE);
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        @Override
        public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion)
        {
            Log.w(TAG, "Upgrading database from version " + oldVersion + " to "
                    + newVersion + ", which will destroy all old data");
            db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS vehicle");
            onCreate(db);
        }
    }

    public DBAdapter open() throws SQLException
    {
        db = DBHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        return this;
    }

    public void close()
    {
        DBHelper.close();
    }

    public long insertVehicle(String _________ (xtimes u want))
    {
        ContentValues initialValues = new ContentValues();
        initialValues.put(_________);
        return db.insert(DATABASE_TABLE, null, initialValues);
    }

    public Cursor getAllVehicles()
    {
        return db.query(DATABASE_TABLE, new String[] {DATABASE_ROW_ID, ____}, null, null, null, null, null);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Qt already has MySql as a built in SQL package for database operations. QSQllite may not be available due to license incompatibilities. If you want to use sqllite, you should install development package for using sqllite services.

Operations like u mentioned are absolutely doable with sqllite.

You can find sqllite examples at http://doc.trolltech.com/4.5/examples.html#sql